# How to override a Model Form widget in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to override `render_option` method present inside `Select` Widget class from my `forms.py` file. So I have added the method with the same name inside the corresponding Model form class. But it won't work (this method fails to override). My `forms.py` file looks like,

```
class CustomSelectMultiple(Select):

    allow_multiple_selected = True

    def render_option(self, selected_choices, option_value, option_label):
        print 'Inside custom render_option\n\n'
        if option_value is None:
            option_value = ''
        option_value = force_text(option_value)
        if option_value in selected_choices:
            selected_html = mark_safe(' selected="selected"')
            if not self.allow_multiple_selected:
                # Only allow for a single selection.
                selected_choices.remove(option_value)
        else:
            selected_html = ''
        return format_html('<option value="{}" data-img-src="www.foo.com" {}>{}</option>',
                           option_value,
                           selected_html,
                           force_text(option_label))

    def render_options(self, choices, selected_choices):
        print 'Inside custom render_options\n\n'
        print self
        print choices
        # Normalize to strings.
        selected_choices = set(force_text(v) for v in selected_choices)
        output = []
        for option_value, option_label in chain(self.choices, choices):
            if isinstance(option_label, (list, tuple)):
                output.append(format_html('<optgroup label="{}">', force_text(option_value)))
                for option in option_label:
                    output.append(self.render_option(selected_choices, *option))
                output.append('</optgroup>')
            else:
                output.append(self.render_option(selected_choices, option_value, option_label))
        #print output
        return '\n'.join(output)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs=None, choices=()):
        print 'Inside custom render\n\n'
        if value is None:
            value = []
        final_attrs = self.build_attrs(attrs, name=name)
        output = [format_html('<select multiple="multiple"{}>', flatatt(final_attrs))]
        options = self.render_options(choices, value)
        if options:
            output.append(options)
        output.append('</select>')
        return mark_safe('\n'.join(output))

    def value_from_datadict(self, data, files, name):
        if isinstance(data, MultiValueDict):
            return data.getlist(name)
        return data.get(name)


class GuideUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GuideUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_modified'].widget = HiddenInput()
        self.fields['point_of_interest'].widget = CustomSelectMultiple()

    class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'image', 'point_of_interest', 'date_modified', )
        model = Guide
```

I also tried changing my `Meta` class like,

```
class Meta:
        fields = ('name', 'image', 'point_of_interest', 'date_modified', )
        model = Guide
        widgets = {
            'point_of_interest': SelectMultiple(attrs={'data-img-src': 'www.foo.com'}),
        }
```

But it add's the attribute `data-img-src` only to the `select` tag but not to all the `option` tags present inside the `select` tag.

Note that `SelectMultiple` class invokes the `renderoptions` method of `Select` class which further invokes the `renderoption` method which don't have `attrs=None` keyword argument.

Comment: @Sayse see [`widget.Select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/forms/widgets/#SelectMultiple)

Comment: Sure, thats what I was getting at, your code snippet above has the method in the form but I can only find reference to it inside the [widget class](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/widgets.py#L528)

Comment: sorry failed to update the code.. Pls check it now.. I tried overriding the in-built methods but it fails to fetch datas from db.

Comment: I've been trying it out and your code does add it to the [options for me](http://imgur.com/G7coSFm) (top snippet not the meta). I'm wondering if caching is to blame perhaps?... Also, if it helps others, I tested it by adding this to a form `forms.ChoiceField(widget=CustomSelectMultiple(), choices=[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')])`

Comment: I added `self.fields['point_of_interest'].widget = forms.ChoiceField(widget=CustomSelectMultiple(), choices=[('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')])` inside `init` method but it shows `'ChoiceField' object has no attribute 'is_hidden'`

Comment: You don't need the `.widget`, in my test code it was creating a field (equivalent to setting `self.fields['p_o_i'] = ` in your above comment)

Comment: ya, it works but I won't get exact db values. I tried printing the `choices` variable but it shows an empty tuple. custom method failed to fetch data from db but the original does.

Comment: I also tried without the overrided methods, ie, printing the self and changing the value of self and then assign the result back to self itself. This also won't work.

Comment: I'm not sure how much more help I can be, I thought the issue was the missing attribute, not sure about the db field.

Comment: @Sayse I managed to solve this problem by passing db values to choices kwargs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging off your own solution it looks like you may have been looking for a [`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield)

```
self.fields['point_of_interest'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=CustomSelectMultiple(),
                                                          queryset=poi.objects.all())
```

The queryset parameter consists of "A QuerySet of model objects from which the choices for the field will be derived, and which will be used to validate the user’s selection."

> does it create a list of tuples of ids, names? Because I want the option tag to look like `option value="id">name</option>`

I'm pretty sure the default is `id, __str__` where `__str__` is the string representation of the model. If you wanted this to be specific to the name then you could override this field and set `label_from_instance`

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return obj.name
```

Comment: does it create a list of tuples of ids, names? Because I want the option tag to look like `option value="id">name</option>`

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Theres an optional [`to_field_name`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.to_field_name) parameter if thats what you were asking about? I'm pretty sure the default value shown to the user is whatever the `__str__` representation is, but yes otherwise the default is `id, __str__` (see the to_field_name_ link for example of default)

Comment: If I use ur method, I'm getting option value as empty string.. My str representation of model is name. plus one for ur effort.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Are you talking about the default empty label you get? or are all option values empty for some reason? I just tested it again and seemed to work ok for me

Comment: @AvinashRaj - No worries, hope it helped, If you were referring to the empty element you could disable that by setting [`empty_label`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label)`=None`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103606/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-sayse).

Comment: I got `Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.` validation error. It automatically adds `<option value="" data-img-src="">---------</option>`

Comment: Solved by using `forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem by passing db values to `choices` kwargs.

```
from models import poi
class GuideUpdateForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GuideUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['date_modified'].widget = HiddenInput()
        self.fields['point_of_interest'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=CustomSelectMultiple(), choices=[(i.id,i.name) for i in poi.objects.all()])
```